# Make relative link absolute in javascript / php

Tags: javascript, php, absolute-path

I have a bug in some of my pages related to a form.

On any page in the root directory, the form works:

```
site.com/page.php
```

On these pages, it does not:

```
site.com/subdomain/page.php
site.com/subdomain/subsubdomain/page.php
```

I think I've traced the problem back to some script tags that are using relative links.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $("#where").autocomplete("autofill_source.php", {
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false
    });
});
</script>
```

There are 3 files being referenced:  2 in src="*.js" part of the code and one (autofill_source.php) in the function part of the code.

My question is, how do I go about making all 3 of these links absolute, keeping in mind it could be referenced from the root folder, or down 2, 3 or more sub-directories.

I've seen it handled with `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` or some other ways, but I just wanted to ask and see what the best solution is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a=document.createElement("a"); a.href="whatev"; alert(a.href);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `autofill_source.php` to `/autofill_source.php`. Slash at the start of the path means the root folder of you web server.
Or, you may get your base URL with `window.location.origin` in JavaScript.

Comment: that seemed to do the trick.  It's okay to do this on the src="" part as well?

Comment: @Kevin, yes, browser will interpret ```autofill_source.php``` as relative to your current path and any path starting with forward slash ```/autofill_source.php``` as relative to the root, regardless of whether it's src of an anchor tag, or img tag, or as in your case.